# sql server 2005 query - random child rows of UNIQUE random parent rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, random, parent-child

I got a parent table 'ProductCategory' and a child table 'Product'. I have this query that returns 3 random products:

```
SELECT    TOP (3) ProductId
FROM      Product
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

I want to enhance that query to achieve that all the products are from different product categories. So the query to get unique categories would be:

```
SELECT    TOP (3) ProductCategoryId
FROM      ProductCategory
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

I am not able to figure out how to combine those 2 queries to achieve my goal. The obvious query

```
SELECT    TOP (3) p.ProductId
FROM      Product p
where p.productcategory_ProductCategoryId in
    (
    SELECT    TOP (3) ProductCategoryId pc
    FROM      ProductCategory pc
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

does not work. It seems like the inner select statement is ignored. I also tried with the EXISTS statement or joining the tables. All with the same result.

Does someone have an idea? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to decouple the 2 queries and this is one solution

Per ProductCategoryId, correlated subquery to get a random product. Uniqueness of ProductCategoryId is handled by the outer query.

```
SELECT TOP 3
    (SELECT TOP 1
        ProductId
    FROM
        Product P
    WHERE
        P.ProductCategoryId = PC.ProductCategoryId
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID()
    ) AS ProductId
FROM
    ProductCategory PC
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
            Product Pex
        WHERE
            Pex.ProductCategoryId = PC.ProductCategoryId)
ORDER BY
    NEWID();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it now!

In Burbidge87's I added a where condition:

```
FROM Product p
where @CategoryID = p.ProductCategory_ProductCategoryId
```

that does it. Thanks again!

JJ

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  I was able to accomplish this task using a temp table and a cursor.  Longer of a step, but it works.

```
create table #temp(
 productID int
,CategoryID int
)
declare @CategoryID int
declare ID_Cursor cursor
for select ProductCategoryID from ProductCategory order by NEWID() 
open ID_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ID_Cursor INTO @CategoryID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 and (select COUNT(*) from #temp)<3
BEGIN

if (@CategoryID not in (select CategoryID from #temp))
Begin
insert into #temp
SELECT top(1) ProductID, @CategoryID
  FROM [Product] 
  order by NEWID() 
 END 

FETCH NEXT FROM ID_Cursor INTO @CategoryID
END 
CLOSE ID_Cursor
DEALLOCATE ID_Cursor

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```